# How do you get a mouse functioning in TTY?

Tags: mouse, tty

I may be asking for the impossible here, but is it possible to use the mouse in tty? I mean not the terminal, but the GUI-less tty itself? And if so, how?

Comment: This belongs to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @dessert you have a point. is it possible to "move" this question to another stack exchange?

Comment: It may be for a mod, but they are busy… Just ask the question there, this here will be closed as off-topic soon.

Comment: @dessert it is possible for mods yes, and since only they can do that, it's reasonable to ask them to handle it, by flagging the post for migration. However, I don't see any particular reason why this question should be closed as off-topic? Why do you think so? You may be right that jack0da is more likely to get a good answer to this question there, but it's not off-topic here. If you know the answer, I recommend posting it...

Comment: @MarkKirby OK, I'm ready to learn otherwise, just that I saw similar questions got closed because they were not primarily about Ubuntu, but rather… well, Unix & Linux.

Comment: @dessert I agree, but the answer to this question is probably varying depending on which linux distro it is, and since I am using something ubuntu-based, possibly the best thing to do is ask it here.

Comment: OK, you convinced me – flag retracted. ;)

Comment: hmm Ubuntu-based != Ubuntu. Mint, elementaryOS, Kali Linux, Zorin etc etc are all *off-topic* here...

Comment: `ncurses` (start with `man ncurses`) has mouse support (`man 3ncurses mouse`)